# Create a dataframe from a Json with multiple objects

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

What I'm trying to do is work with a json database with multiple objects in a single file. The problem is that I was unable to come up with a viable solution to transform this json file into a dataset. Based on your experiences, what is the best way to do this using Pandas?

Download the json here: https://gofile.io/d/fEufLx

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With almost no information about your json formatting, I can only recommend pandas.read_json(). The documentation can be found here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html.

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot to send the image!